# Difference between php -S localhost:8000 and httpd -k start

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I'm just set a new computer to work on, so I install Apache24, PHP and MySQL.

I use the different tutorial, and I could launch a "server" from `php -S localhost:8000` or I could do it from  `httpd -k start`.

In my .conf

```
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
# ServerName localhost:80

# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80 Listen 127.0.0.1:1000
```

And I don't understand what is the difference? 
I could access to `127.0.0.1:1000` and I see my directory htdocs but It' work even if I don't start httpd.

It's a bit a big mess in my head between, what is a server that is not a server why some port work why other not.
If I check with netstat, it only show : 1000 listening.

In the end, I want to test some stuff with a "simple" php server before try it on symfony server.
By advance, Thanks for your help. :D
Axel

Comment: There are many web servers out there, not just Apache: IIS, nginx, Lighttpd, Node.js... Your tutorial describes how to launch two of them (Apache HTTP Server and PHP built-in server).

Answer (score 1):

`php -S` starts the [built in PHP web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

`httpd` starts an [Apache web server](https://httpd.apache.org/) using PHP to process PHP files.

If you just want to test a couple of things locally, the built in PHP web server is probably fine - it's lightweight and easy to spin up and close down.

If you want a full web server you should use Apache. It's probably not working because it's either not configured correctly for your environment, your PHP version or your document root. There's plenty of resources online for setting up Apache locally, depending on your operating system.

Comment: Hi Robbie, thanks for the answer :D . So I understand they're both web server. PHP is just design for testing code on a local environment contrary to Apache which, after some setting, allow to deployed a full website.

Answer (score 1):

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php:

`php -S localhost:8000` starts PHPs builtin webserver (not as many features). Your site will be available at `http://localhost:8000` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. Files will be served from the directory you executed it.

https://httpd.apache.org/:

`httpd -k start` starts the Apache webserver. Your site (if not configured otherwise) will be available at `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1`. Can/must be configured if you want to use a different directory than the default one.